# issue with surface with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
a = 10:100
b = 10:100
c = power(a,b)
surf(a,b,c)
```

=> Error using surf (line 78)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector

any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

`c=power(a,b)` does not give you the combinations of all `a` power `b`, unfortunately.

Here there is a way of doing it (though most likely there is a vectorizedd way of doing it)

```
a = 10:100;
b = linspace(1,10,length(a)); 
% I changed the values of b, because 100^100 is that a big number that Matlab will not plot it, it is too big for storing in a double

%loop and save
for ii=1:length(b)
   c(ii,:)=a.^(b(ii)); 
end

surf(a,b,c)
```

[image]

Comment: The vectorized way: `[A,B]=meshgrid(a,b); C=A.^B ; surf(A,B,C)`.

Comment: @Hoki Indeed. I was thinking more something like Luis's answer. `bsxfun` scares and amazes me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
a = 10:100;
b = 1:.1:10; %// changed b to avoid very large numbers
c = bsxfun(@power, a, b.');
surf(a,b,c)
```

Comment: ok, why di you change b ? and just a question in c = bsxfun(@power, a, b.');
what 's "b.' "?

Comment: I changed it for the same reason as @Ander did: the numbers become too large with your original `b`. `b.'` is just the transpose of `b`.  You need to transpose one of the vectors so that `bsxfun` computes all combinations